# background-position: right center no funciona en hover

Tags: html, css, html5, scss

mi problema es el siguiente estoy tratando de lograr una especie de efecto destello como el que aparece en los botones de la siguiente [web](https://gradientbuttons.colorion.co/)

el problema que no me funciona el `:hover`

mi estructura es la siguiente

```css
.grad-blue {
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00c6ff 0%, #0072ff 51%, #00c6ff 100%);
 border: none;
    border-radius: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    width: 72px;
    margin: auto 13px;
}

.grad-blue:hover { 
 background-position: right center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-opt" style=" position: absolute; bottom: 30px; color: #fff; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;">
  <button type="button" class="grad-blue">OPCION</button>
  <button type="button" class="grad-blue">OPCION</button>
  <button type="button" class="grad-blue">OPCION</button>
</div>
```

Como ven al pasar el mouse por encima no ejecuta el css...

DATOS ADICIONALES: Mi navegador es la última versión de chrome y mi so es win 10 x64 y probe cambiar las etiquetas  por  y tampoco tuve suerte

desde ya gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @Macali lo que te falto poner en el CSS fue solo un poco de transicion y claro el hover no se movera solo, debes ponerle el numero de px que se movera en este caso del mismo width del boton

```
.grad-blue {
background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00c6ff 0%, #0072ff 51%, #00c6ff 100%);
border: none;
border-radius: 72px;
height: 72px;
width: 72px;
margin: auto 13px;
}

.grad-blue:hover { 
 transition: 0.2s linear;
 background-position: left 72px center; 
}
```

Comment: excelente amigo! funcionó muchas gracias